# Firebase $save doesn't work inside an event handler function

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I must be missing something really basic. I have an input box where the list name is entered. The name is then saved to the Firebase.

When using `$watch`, it works just fine. However, if done through `ng-keyup` event, it returns the following error

> TypeError: undefined is not a function.

What am I missing?

HTML:

```
<input id="which_list" ng-keyup="enterThis($event)" ng-model="which_list.name" >{{which_list.name}}</span>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.which_list = sync.$asObject();

$scope.$watch('which_list.name', function() {
   gDataService.which_list.name= $scope.which_list.name;
    $scope.which_list.$save()    // THIS WORKS
                                // $scope.which_list => d {$$conf: Object, $id: "id", $priority: null, name: "to1_list", $save: function…}
    .then(function(){  
        console.log($scope.which_list.name);
    });
});

$scope.enterThis = function(event){
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        gDataService.which_list.name= $scope.which_list.name;
        $scope.which_list.$save();   // THIS DOESN't WORK
                                     // $scope.which_list = Object {name:"list_name"}

    }
};
```

EDIT: In the comment, I included the value of `$scope.which_list` shown at the breakpoint.

Comment: `undefined is not a function` is JavaScripts equivalent of a nullpointer exception. Did you try putting a breakpoint inside `enterThis` and checking that state at that point?

Comment: Yes. Included the value of $scope.which_list in the comments above. I don't understand why it becomes a simple object (instead of firebase sync object) within the enterThis function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently as you are changing in scope `which_list` converting to  plain old JavaScript objects (POJO), I believe you need to unable 3 way binding between scope variable and `$asObject()`.

**Code**

```
var which_list = sync.$asObject();
// set up 3-way data-binding
which_list.$bindTo($scope, "which_list");
```

**Update**

Also as you are using `$scope.which_list` object which contains name and other property,So do initialize it on starting of your controller like

```
$scope.which_list = {}
```

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it turned out I made a mistake of assigning {} to which_list along the way when using the event handler. I fixed the issue by correcting the unintended assignment, but I believe pankajparkar's answer would have fixed it too. Thanks.

Comment: @javvvva  I updated the answer..kindly do check..feel free to edit.. Thanks :)